# Simulation of arduino mega 2560 with GSM Module using proteus

Tags: arduino, embedded, simulation

have really been suffering with my simulation! Tried connecting my arduino mega 2560 to COMPIM (used as GSM Module) in my circuit and also loaded sample code but damn! In vain! I wanted to view the data sent in virtual terminal but am getting nothing! and its also complaining of excessive CPU usage.

[image]

And thereafter, the messages are displayed as shown below.

[image]

Someone please help me out. Am I making a mistake oh? Infact the arduino code for displaying in the simulation is also giving me hard time. The one am using is as shown below.

```html
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}
```

Will b every grateful for any help offered.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I just want to point out that there is a specialised site for questions about Arduino: http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lister. I actually didn't know about it.

Comment: On the other hand, this site here has many times more visitors than that one, so it's possible you'll get an answer more quickly here.

Comment: Oh thanks alot. I also added a link  via the same site link is below http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9374/simulation-of-arduino-mega-2560-with-gsm-module-using-proteus

Comment: All I can say is that SwSerial is not a particularly nice library to the system.
Sure it does what it claims, but it busy waits in interrupt context inbetween bits from the serial port.
This can cause problems to a system that relies in interrupts for other tasks.
Especially if the port uses a low baud rate.
All in all, better use some other board that has as many HW serial ports as needed.